# Continue Test on TestNG with failures

Tags: java, testng

I have a Test method with 2 assertions. The first assertion code fails, and because of that the 2nd one is not running.

How can I make all the line to run, without using SoftAsserter? I wish to accumulate all the errors, and at the and of my method to throw them.

Here is an example of my code:

```
@Test
public void SimpleTest()
{
    asserter.assertEquals(true,false);
    asserter.assertEquals(5,5);
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use SoftAssert? It is designed to do what you need.

Comment: SoftAssert seems to be designed precisely for that purpose...

Comment: Because it effects some other code. I must use normal Asserter and make it go back to the test, and not failing it

Comment: "it effects some other code" - what do you mean ?

Comment: So the only idea I have is to place each assert in separate try-catch, and in catch block add exception to collection of exceptions what you handle somehow at the end of test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could rewrite your tests without SoftAssert:

```
@Test
public void simpleTestFailure() {
    check(
            () -> Assert.assertEquals(true, false),
            () -> Assert.assertEquals(5, 5));
}

@Test
public void simpleTestOK() {
    check(
            () -> Assert.assertEquals(5, 5));
}

private void check(Runnable... runnables) {
    boolean success = true;
    int index = 0;
    for (Runnable runnable : runnables) {
        try {
            index++;
            runnable.run();
            System.out.println(String.format("Assertion %s succeeded", index));
        } catch (AssertionError ae) {
            System.err.println(String.format("Assertion %s failed:\n%s", index, ae));
            ae.printStackTrace(System.err);
            success = false;
        }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(success);
}
```

This solution can be further refined to better match your needs.

Comment: The only thing I would change is for `check` to take Runnable... as input and evaluate internally if all of tasks completed successfully.
Nevertheless this is what I was talking about!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> @Test(alwaysRun=true)

test execution will continue no matter previous test has failed.